# File Download speed is 60kbps but speedtest shows 5.7mbps. Why is that?

Tags: internet, internet-speed

My speed test on checking shows 5.7 Mbps but when i try to download files: it downloads in the speed of 60 kbps only? I'm getting a lot of nuisance.
 Help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server that provides the files might be limiting the speed, either intentionally, or because many people download files from it in parallel.

To test, try to download files from other sources.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we check the speed of any connection on servers, it shows the UPLINK and DOWNLINK speed of the server or network.

While downloading the file, it solely does not depend on the server network but also the Sharing ratio of the network you have connected to. Like if you have 2mbps of Downlink speed, and the sharing ratio is 1:8, then you might end up downloading at speed of around 65kbps to 100kbps. But this only occurs with the download speed, not the buffer speed like: loading youtube, or anything else.